# Get the value of CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER from cURL

Tags: php, curl, php-7

I have the method below that is to get the response from **webserver** using **cURL**.

```
function login (string $_login, string $_password) : string {

    $url = "https://acweb.net.br/api/orcamentos/login";  

    $fields = [
        "login"    => $_login,
        "password" => $_password
    ];

    $headers = [
        "Try" => "Trying"
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    return curl_exec( $ch );

}
```

It works fine!

i can get the value of **$_POST** with

```
print_r ($_POST)
```

But i can't get the value of **CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER**.

**EDIT:**

I did try so:

```
print_r ($_SERVER)
```

but it wasn't there.

How can i get the value of **CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER**?

all **HTTP_headers** in **$_SERVER**:

```
[HTTP_HOST] => ctemcasb.com.br
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
[HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
[HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER] => ?1
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
[HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE] => none
[HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE] => navigate
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
[HTTP_COOKIE] => PHPSESSID=j4cqqdc83fia68nk0gsglqk1bv
```

**HTTP_TRY**, not exists.

And now?

I did this in the server:

```
print_r($_SERVER)
```

and

```
print_r ($_SERVER["HTTP_TRY]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The headers shouldn't be an associative array, it should be an indexed array of strings.

```
$headers = [
    'Try: Trying',
    'Content-Type: text/html',
    ...
];
```

Then you should be able to access the header with: `$_SERVER['HTTP_TRY']` since custom headers are prefixed with `HTTP_`

Comment: The, i put on the end of question explain that i dont be able to do.

Comment: @CarlosRocha - I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you mean. I tested your code, both your way of adding headers and the above way. Your way didn't work but the above did.

Comment: see in the end of the question please

Comment: Ii am doing so print_r( $_SERVER['HTTP_TRY']);, and said that not exists.

Comment: @CarlosRocha - I can't answer that, since it works when I test it. There must be something else going on somewhere else. Check that you don't have some extension installed/enabled, web server config or similar that filters custom headers.

Comment: Can you post a reply doing of way that you did?

Comment: @CarlosRocha - I copy/pasted your code. I only changed the URL to a local file that only contained `var_dump($_POST, $_SERVER);`. I called the function ´echo login('foo', 'bar');`. I saw the post-data but not the `HTTP_TRY` header. Second attempt, I changed the headers to match this answer, ran the code and got back both the post-data and the `HTTP_TRY` header. So if it doesn't work for you, there must be something else causing your issue.

Comment: Then after of o study very very, i found the problem: I was trying get the $_SERVER["HTTP_TRY"], as you say me but in the same page. It shoud be in the sever page, not cliente page. Cause it not works. Now works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CarlosRocha - If you feel that this answer helped you solve it, feel free to accept it so others know the issue's been resolved. But when I see that you haven't accepted _any_ answer on any of your questions, I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: Ok, thank for talk-me! Done e thank you for tjy reply!